# Back up boot records, partition metadata and data into a single archive file

Tags: linux, backup, archive, restore

Back in the days I have used `Acronis` (commercial software) which was great.

You could create a backup of a hard drive which resulted in one single file.

That file contained all the information necessary to be able to restore the backup into a blank hard drive. Boot records, partition tables, and data would be restored.

The single file did not occupy more space than the data on the drive used. It is far superior do `dd` (which I agree is a bit like comparing apples to oranges). Data-requirement and speed-wise.

Now to my question:

Is there a similar open-source and maintained tool in Linux?

It should ideally also be possible to run in from an existing system and backup an connected `USB` or `SD` storage with all its details.

I am aware of `Clonezilla` but as far as I understand it is a live-system. I would like a tool which can be started from a running OS, which is `Fedora` in my case.

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not sure whether or not there exists a ready-made tool that does it all, but you certainly should be able to put something together without too much difficulty. For example, you could save the partition tables (yes, plural) using `sfdisk`/`sgdisk`, partition boot sector using `dd`, and the extN file system data using `dump` (to be restored using `restore`), then bundle it all together using `tar`, possibly with compression (`7z`, `bzip`, `xz`, ...) and/or encryption (`gpg`) tacked on.